# NaN value in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

[image]

I'm working with node and mongodb 5. I have the following code in my node script:

```
       for (let i = 0; i < combinedArr.length; i++) {
            const element = combinedArr[i]
            if (element.includes('Yearly Dues:')) {
                assessed = combinedArr[i + 1];
                assessed = Number(assessed.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ''));
            }        
            else if (element.includes('Total Amount Due')) {
                totalDue = combinedArr[i + 1];
                totalDue = Number(totalDue.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ''));
            }


        }

        let ratio;
        (totalDue/assessed).toFixed(2);
        console.log('ratio: ',ratio);
```

In many cases the assessed value is 0, leading to ratio of NaN. Is this the same as infinity from the mongo perspective. As you can see in the screenshot, I'd like to select for actual values of greater than 1.1, but not inclusing NaN.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Check if assessed === 0 and special case it

Comment: I think you can use something like this: `{ $and: [ {Ration: { $gt: 1.1 } }, { Ration: { $ne: NaN } } ]}`

Comment: You are comparing strings: `{Ratio: {$gt: '1.1'}}` and string-wise `NaN` is greater than `1.1`. Try comparing numbers instead: `{Ratio: {$gt: 1.1}}`.

Comment: Yes, came here to say what @HeikoTheißen points out. You want to compare _and store_ the value as a number in the first place.